# ContactsApp getFullName() returns nothing from contacts added from Directory

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

1. I have Google Directory that I want to share contacts and their information within my domain
2. I go to domain user's google contacts and add all the directory contacts into "My Contacts"

Problem: I can't get the name from the specified contact when I add my Directory contacts into "My Contacts". There are some strange solutions I've found:

- I have to email the contact before being able to get his/her name
- OR I would have to manually add the contacts with google app scripting (GAS) into a new contact group
- SIDE NOTE: I can successfully get the emails fine using this method. It's just information like the name that is a problem

  ```
      var svContacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();
      for (var i=0; i<svContacts.length; i++) {
       var nameStr  = svContacts[i].getFullName();
       Logger.log(nameStr);
      }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I can't be 100% sure, but I suspect strongly that adding a contact from the shared directory to your own contacts doesn't really copy it over until you do something that edits the contact (like sending them an email or adding them to a group). Apps Script sees the same contacts that are exposed in the Google Contacts GData API, but it does not currently have the ability to see directory contacts, so this would explain your results.